# PowerShell WhereObjectCommand from C#

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to call the following PS script from C#:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -IncludePreExchange2007 -Status | Where-Object {$_.Server -eq 'myserver'}
```

I have managed to execute the first part before the pipe using this code:

```
  public void Test()
  {
     using (Pipeline pipeline = _runspace.CreatePipeline())
     {
        var cmd1 = new Command("Get-MailboxDatabase");
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("IncludePreExchange2007");
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("Status");

        var cmd2 = new Command("Where-Object");
        //how do I script {$_.Server -eq 'myserver'} ???

        pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd1);
        //pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd2);

        Collection<PSObject> result = pipeline.Invoke();
     }
  }
```

but how do I script the second part for Where-Object???

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use LINQ:

```
result.Where(p => (string)p.Properties["Server"].Value == "myserver"));
```

Comment: you're right, probably I won't get better performance as this filter will be applied after i get all the results from the first command

Answer (score 0):

I am updating this thread in case another user visits this question.

To **enhance the performance** you can perform filtering in the PowerShell itself and can use Where-Object there. I have provided the answer here: [Calling PowerShell's where-object from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796176/calling-powershells-where-object-from-c-sharp/36798605#36798605)

Essentially, you will need to use Add Script instead of adding command like below:

```
    //Getting all command variables
    string myServer = "ServerName";

    //Create Script command
    String customScriptText = String.Format("Get-MailboxDatabase -IncludePreExchange2007 -Status | Where-Object {{$_.Server -eq \"{0}\"}}", myServer);

    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(customScriptText);
```

**Note** to escape `{ and }` using double curly braces i.e. `{{` and `}}`. Also escape quotes as `\"` using back slash in the String.Format method.