# Calling PowerShell's where-object from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-4.0

How can I call `Where-Object` (without filter) from C#? I can't parse output, because I want to pass it to pipeline(not in example below).

PS:

```
Get-MailboxPermission username | Where-Object {$_.AccessRights -match "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $False}
```

C#:

```
Collection<PSObject> results = null;

Command command1 = new Command("Get-MailboxPermission");
command1.Parameters.Add("Identity", mailbox);
command1.Parameters.Add("DomainController", _domainController);
//I cannot use Filter. This is not possible in PS also.
//command1.Parameters.Add("Filter", "AccessRights -match \"FullAccess\"");
```

This question is simmilar to: [PowerShell WhereObjectCommand from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104222/powershell-whereobjectcommand-from-c-sharp) That answer is not enough for my problem.

Comment: `Filter` should be `ScriptBlock` not `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code sample. I have updated a sample from code project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) as per your requirements.

**Note:**

1. To add quotes to your command i.e. script text escape quotes by using `\"`
2. To add `{` or `}` brace to the script text use double curly braces instead to escape it inside String.Format like `{{` or `}}`

   ```
   // create Powershell runspace
   Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

   // open it
   runspace.Open();

   // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
   Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

   //Getting all command variables
   string computerName = "YourComputerName";
   string matchingPattern = "con";

   //Create Script command
   String customScriptText = String.Format("Get-Process -ComputerName {0} | Where-Object {{$_.ProcessName -match \"{1}\"}}", computerName,matchingPattern);

   pipeline.Commands.AddScript(customScriptText);

   // add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
   // remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns.
   pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

   // execute the script
   Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

   // close the runspace
   runspace.Close();

   // convert the script result into a single string
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (PSObject obj in results)
   {
       stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
   }
   ```

When you apply the above working sample to your problem you will need to change couple of lines like below:

```
    //Getting all command variables
    string username = "YourUserName";

    //Create Script command
    String customScriptText = String.Format("Get-MailboxPermission {0} | Where-Object {{$_.AccessRights -match \"FullAccess\" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $False}}", username);
```

Comment: Do you know why I always keep getting 
`Script block literals are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section.` exception?

Comment: You need to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` on the target machine.

Comment: What can you do if you don't have the authority to use "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"?  Is there anyway to use the where-object clause without using a custom script?